# React Send Data from Child to Parent with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to send data from Child Component to Parent component, using Typescript. There are lot of resources, but many don't explore typescript concept.

On the Parent, how would I set the ProductType event? Is this the proper way using React.ChangeEvent? We are using a dropdown selector with Material UI.

```
onProductTypeChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
         setProductType(e.target.value)}
```

Full Code:

**Parent:**

```
const ProductExport = () => {
 const [productType, setProductType] = useState<undefined | string>('');

 return (
 <>
 <ProductFilters
      productTypeValue={productType}
      onProductTypeChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
         setProductType(e.target.value)}
 />
```

**Child:**

```
type Props = {
  productTypeValue?: string;
  onProductTypeChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
};

const ProductFilters = ({
  productTypeValue,
  onProductTypeChange
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary>
          <Typography>Products</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Box >
            <Box>
              <TextField
                select
                value={productTypeValue}
                onChange={onProductTypeChange}
                label={'Select Product Type'}
              >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you hide the internal details in the Child (the actual event), and expose to the parent only the result (new data):

```
// Parent
const ProductExport = () => {
 const [productType, setProductType] = useState<undefined | string>('');

 return (
   <ProductFilters
      productTypeValue={productType}
      onProductTypeChange={setProductType}
   />
  );
}

// Child
type Props = {
  productTypeValue?: string;
  onProductTypeChange?: (newType: string) => void;
};

const ProductFilters = ({
  productTypeValue,
  onProductTypeChange
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      select
      value={productTypeValue}
      onChange={(event) => onProductTypeChange?.(event.target.value)}
      label={'Select Product Type'}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: TS (and your IDE) should infer the type of `event` based on the type of the MUI `<TextField>` `onChange` prop

Comment: That is the advantage of keeping that event local: here it is inferred, you do not need to copy its type anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

React has a preprepared type for multiple event handlers, such `ChangeEventHandler` ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=24&ssc=3&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLYDCAFigHYDmSAogG5IMwASjAJgBskUOAF84AMygQQcAORRUGeQG4AsACgtMAJ5gkcAAoywhOAF5cWuHDAz%20%20DABV9SAGopB%20JAH4AXHCEMFDAzBqathAMJhCOLm50jCyBScxsnNx8DEIiADw8zgCyADIAkgxg%20DCswiBcMAB8EWIRWmjRwcYOTjAAYsCClFDmVgAUODZ2PQkGnt5UU9Gx8TCuBmksWmKBsWYAlJaNcAz4goJtmh0MXSu9rAAekLCWcGOHFseTkXDXXQDa9jivXWVCCSBgd1mSAAuq8iKRyJQ8vgckhJGEkPw4AAfIIhMJMRpjeTyfaXWx-eDLGZrRL0dKpBksDgNbK5KAFYrlSrVWpIercY5WQyfcGQ2mgsZIAB05CgLBgMvYXh85K0UyUMHwUAYbymtjyUP6g2GhAN02B0PmPgsOCBq1BYgtNKtdI2zKQdtdjvpySQzp%20tgA9I0purNK0NZogA)):

```
type Props = {
  productTypeValue?: string;
  onProductTypeChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
};

const ProductFilters = ({
  productTypeValue,
  onProductTypeChange
}: Props) => null;

const ProductExport = () => {
  const [productType, setProductType] = useState<undefined | string>('');

  const onProductTypeChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = e => setProductType(e.target.value);

  return (
    <ProductFilters
      productTypeValue={productType}
      onProductTypeChange={onProductTypeChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: this is helpful, however its only changing the data type to something else, I appreciate it! what do you think of other answer btw from ghybs? both answers work

Comment: It's a good answer for a specific purpose component, such as your. It's less usable if you want to create a general input component, such as a custom input, and you want to preserver the controlled input api.